# Hard-coding a path in a dll, or How to write a wrapper

Tags: c#, architecture, installation, wrapper

I made a [wrapper](https://github.com/AwokeKnowing/GnuplotCSharp) to gnuplot in C#.  Currently it's just a cs file that's a class.  The class pipes commands to/from gnuplot.exe.  Currently, you'd have to go into the code, set the path to wherever your gnuplot is, then recompile.

```
class GnuPlot
    {
        public static string PathToGnuplot = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin";
```

What's the proper way to structure a wrapper that depends on an .exe in people's system?  Do people want a config file? a whole install msi just to confirm where the path to gnuplot is?

When people make a 3rd party gui for a command line program, how do they handle distribution of the program and linking up with the presumably already installed command line program?

Comment: One option would be to learn if the program that you want to use stores that data in the registry. If not, I would go with a properties file, and either add a "setup program" or inform the program of its existence and how to edit it(of course, it should depend of your target audience)

Comment: thanks, I suppose an installer could try to find it in a couple locations, and if not found, it could let you browse or provide you a link to download it.   It's just that it's a light wrapper and I don't want to make a monster out of it when it's just 1 class with a few dozen wrapper and utility methods.  Perhaps a runtime message box letting you browse.. and include a link in the message box.  That would of course, be an implementation of the config file option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really going to be delivering this program to users I would recommend including the `exe` in the build output and referencing it with a relative path. This will ensure the program always works. If it's more like an internal tool or something that doesn't require such a nice user experience then just put the path in the `App.Config` or some other ini/config file. Read the path from there and use it where you have the hard coded path.

Comment: Thanks, can you think of any examples of other tools or wrappers and how they've done it.  I think you're probably right about including the exe, except I'd need to check the license issues.  I believe the github app (which is a fascinating beast on windows actually) has a local copy of git that it uses, separate from a user's git installation.

Comment: @AwokeKnowing almost all consumer software uses the first option I described. Developer tools often times require you to resolve the dependencies yourself. If it's something common in Windows or .NET then the app might just search their local file system using some hint paths. Given that's a gnu app it's probably fine to use, it's most likely under this license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Comment: yeah, true about consumer soft. But so yes, as its a wrapper for a developer to use, technically that Developer should include gnuplot in his final product.  But as a developer, if YOU knew of gnuplot and you wanted to visualize some data in c# using it, how would you want the wrapper to handle the dependency?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing Personally I'd prefer for it to all be packaged together so I don't have to deal with anything more than what's necessary.

Comment: so if you got it as a nuget package, you'd expect it to add a dll and an exe to your main source folder and set your project to copy them both to the output directory?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing yes, that would be my preference.